# Yahoo News API In C#

Tags: c#, xml, yahoo-api

So I'm working on a speech recognition program in C# and while trying to implement the YAHOO News API into the program I am getting no response.

I won't copy/paste my whole code as it would be very long so here are the main bits.

```
private void GetNews()
{
    string query = String.Format("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");
    XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
    wData.Load(query);

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");

    XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
    XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item/description", manager);

    FirstStory = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("title", manager).Attributes["alt"].Value;

}
```

I believe I have done something wrong here:

```
XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item/description", manager);

FirstStory = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("title", manager).Attributes["alt"].Value;
```

Here is the full XML Document: http://news.yahoo.com/rss/

If any more info is required let me know.

Comment: Well, you say you think you're getting no response. Have you tried setting a break point after the `Load` call on `wData` to see if you have an Xml document?

Comment: I didn't think I'd need one because I managed to get this working on the Weather API but for some reason it doesn't work on the News API. Like I said, I think the last 3/4 lines of code I posted is where the problem is but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question. If you are truly not getting a response from the API, then you won't have an XML document after calling `Load`, and consequently, the rest of your code will be irrelevant. If you *do*, however, get a response, then we can talk about the rest.

Comment: Oh.. I see.. I am getting no response at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I have implemented my own code to get news from Yahoo, I read all the news Title ( which is located at rss/channel/item/title ) and Short story ( which is located rss/channel/item/description ).

The short story is the problem for news, and that is the point when we need to get all the inner text of description node in a string and then parse it like XML. The text code is in this format and the Short story is right behind `</p>`

`<p><a><img /></a></p>"Short Story"<br clear="all"/>`

We need to modify it since we have many xml roots (p and br) and we add an extra root `<me>`

```
string ShStory=null;
string Title = null;

//Creating a XML Document
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  

//Loading rss on it
doc.Load("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");

//Looping every item in the XML
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item"))
{
    //Reading Title which is simple
    Title = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;

    //Putting all description text in string ndd
    string ndd =  node.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;

    XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();

    //Loading modified string as XML in xm with the root <me>
    xm.LoadXml("<me>"+ndd+"</me>");

    //Selecting node <p> which has the text
    XmlNode nodds = xm.SelectSingleNode("/me/p");

   //Putting inner text in the string ShStory
    ShStory= nodds.InnerText;

   //Showing the message box with the loaded data
    MessageBox.Show(Title+ "    "+ShStory); 
}
```

Choose the me as the right answer or vote me up if the code works for you. If there are any issues you can ask me. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I am a beginner at C# could you please provide an example? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you are passing that namespace manager to those attributes, but I'm not 100% certain. Those are definitely not in that `.../mrss/` namespace, so I would guess that is your problem.

I would try it without passing the namespace (if possible) or using the `GetElementsByTagName` method to avoid namespace issues.

Comment: Oh.. Could you elaborate or show me an example as I am new to this, I don't know much.

Comment: Well... i'm not exactly sure on the namespace part since I haven't used the XmlDocument api much (I prefer XDocument), but the other way i suggested you would just do wData.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("channel") and then keep doing that to nest in.

Comment: I should say, the first method, I think you just need to remove the `manager` parameter from the SelectNode calls (assuming it's not required) because I think rss and that is in an empty namespace.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Could you please look at the Xml Document?

Answer (score 0):

Tag contains the text rather than Xml. 
Here is an example to display text news:

```
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
     Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(node.InnerXml, 
                           "(?<=(/a&gt;)).+(?=(&lt;/p))"));
     Console.WriteLine();
}
```